# Enable Search option in SharePoint for Site Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience

I have a problem here for some users in SharePoint, where for some users "Search this Pages" or "Search" is enabled but for some it is hidden or not displayed. How to enable this option for users or is it related to the user profile. This search is under Site Pages (Page Library) modern experience to search .aspx pages

[image]

Comment: Are both users trying to search site pages on same site? I believe this functionality is available only in communication site.

Comment: Yes we have multiple users in this site

Comment: And this is communication site, as i have briefed it is working for some users but for some it is not. I could not able to understand how can this be enabled. For the users which was hidden

Answer (score 0):

The "search this library" feature is being moved to the bar at the top of the page. (same bar as the app launcher). Does this not appear either?

The search bar is a bit confusing at this point: if you're on the home page, the search is for the site. If you're in a library, then the same search box is just for that library.

Comment: "Search this Site" works fine and it does appear on the Home Page, the search what i am thinking is when you create site pages under "Site Pages" folder if you have noticed the image you can search those site pages f.e: "Test1", "Test2".

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, the search box is up top in communication site.

[image]

In Microsoft 365 admin center, go to the Settings > Organization profile page->Next to Release preferences, select Edit->choose "Targeted release for everyone".

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Modern-Document-library-Search-box-gone/m-p/568055

Comment: Thank you for the answer, for some reason i could not identify what is going wrong. But certain users cannot see the search bar, which is located beside new-menu like in the image of main question and not the "Search this site". I can see the search and some other users but there are few more who does not.

Comment: And how often will this work for team sites ?

Comment: How can we work for team sites to enable the search? can this be possible as per Access or user profile ?